# How do Jedi not turn to the dark side if they study it?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, sith

This is a thing I recently thought about quite a lot:

The dark side gains power from strong and/or negative emotions. Now okay I do get that the Jedi can "surpress" these emotions to a certain degree but since they are emotions they are almost unexplainable to someone who has never felt said.

Also the dark side has always been a problem for Jedi. But yet there are still Jedi that study the how (not) and why (not) of the dark side and the sith. They know what they must do to not fall to the dark side.

How exactly are Jedi able to study the dangers of the dark side without being corrupted?

Comment: I can study the danger of shooting myself in the face with a gun without ever shooting myself in the face with a gun.

Comment: @phantom42 yes but gunshots are not triggered by thinking about a firing gun ;) emotions are triggered by thinking about something

Comment: Emotions aren't necessarily triggered by studying something either.

Comment: “gunshots are not triggered by thinking about a firing gun ;)” — accidental shots aside, I reckon thinking about firing a gun is a pretty vital precursor to a gunshot. “emotions are triggered by thinking about something” — there is some research indicating that bodily movements (e.g. smiling or frowning) can trigger emotions.

Comment: You mean only Vulcans can be true Jedi?

Comment: @SachinShekhar they are the best Jedi Prospects. LOL

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Good and evil are complex and difficult concepts and, whether we like it or not, an important part of the human condition and human nature. Because of this, they show up, in many different ways, in all forms of art - art being one of the ways in which humans work to understand themselves and their place in the world. The two sides of the force are names, symbols, and/or manifestations of good and evil created by George Lucas for the Star Wars universe.

Your question is rooted in a common misconception - that evil cannot be understood by someone unless they, themselves are evil. Further, there are people who believe that authors who depict great evil in their stories must somehow identify with, espouse, or even practice the particular form of evil that is present in their story. (Yes, really.)

And the reality is that one does not have to be evil in order to understand evil. All that is required is [empathy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/empathy): "capacity to understand another person's point of view or the result of such understanding". Understanding does not require agreement, any more than writing a story about a murder makes one a murderer.

Comment: Yep. Evil is actually really easy to understand. Any child who's hit a sibling or had a tantrum when they didn't get their way understands selfishness and violence completely.  The idea that evil is somehow mysterious is nonsense perpetrated by people trying to excuse their own bad behaviour or avoid responsibility for not dealing with it. Gavin De Becker's [The Gift of Fear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gift_of_Fear) explains this in a way that makes it self-evident (and it just might save your life, highly recommmended).